# How can I print all of web page "Are you generic" by Wilson Miner?

Tags: windows, printing, web

How can I print all of the page
http://www.wilsonminer.com/posts/2006/may/10/are-you-generic/ ?

When I print only **two** pages are printed: the beginning of
the web page (until "Note: I’m just going to document the
steps I took to put") and an almost empty page containing
the very last line of the web page, "© 2002-2009 Wilson
Miner. Powered by Django. Hosted by WebFaction."

I expect on the order of 10 printed pages.

Printing works in general and printing other long web pages
works without any problems, e.g.
http://www.rossp.org/blog/2006/jun/23/building-blog-django-4/
and [http://producingoss.com/](http://www.rossp.org/blog/2006/jun/23/building-blog-django-4/).

The problem is present with both Opera and Firefox.
JavaScript is blocked in both browsers.

Platform: Opera 9.64, Firefox 3.0.6, Windows XP 64 bit SP2,
2 GB RAM (900 MB free at time of printing).

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour, even in print preview, only the first page is printed, then a blank one, nothing more. Maybe something css related?

Comment: In Opera, printed out 13 pages, comments included, not sure how you're not getting them all.

Comment: Got the same result on print preview as echo did on IE8. On Firefox 3.5.2, I'm also seeing what fretje describes...this is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the text into Microsoft Word or OpenOffice, and then print that instead. This also lets you tweak the margins and font-size to save paper.

Another suggestion which also works is to disable CSS (perhaps using something like the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) toolbar for Firefox) and then print that version instead. I guess this also confirms it's a CSS issue.

Comment: Microsoft Word handles pasted web pages pretty well.

Comment: Yes, this works great as a work-around. I just tried it using OpenOffice and saved some paper by deleting most of the blog comments. On the other hand I probably spend too much time doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This web site should be just what you need:

[PrintWhatYouLike.com](http://www.PrintWhatYouLike.com)

It's a free website that lets you format any web page for printing.

You start by entering the URL of the page you want to print. The PrintWhatYouLike online editor lets you remove, resize, and rearrange the page elements quickly so you can print only what you want.

It works pretty well for me.

Comment: +1. Bookmarked! As I understand, it would not work though with pages that requires login.

Comment: I think it requires JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a good 12 page PDF file using the firefox [PDFDownload](http://www.pdfdownload.org/) addon.
Maybe you should try that -- quite a handy addon.